# Apache RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file

```
# Redirect every request to index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule .* to public/index.php
```

And i'm receiving the following error in the error.log:

> RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

What's wrong with the .htaccess file? (I just started stying mod_rewrite module).

Edit: the .htaccess file is in the site's root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "`to`":

```
RewriteRule .* public/index.php
```

[Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Just one more thing, when i use `RewriteRule .* public/index.php` looks like if the web server is stuck and i don't receive any response, but if i use `RewriteRule .* test.html` i'm corretly redirected to test.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you don't need a "to" in the rewrite rule. just delete that word and it should be ok.

```
RewriteRule .* public/index.php
```

The [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) go into this in depth.

Answer (score -1):

The other ones are right, but don't forget to keep what's after the `?` in the URL, it's the `QSA` flag, like this:

```
# Redirect every request to index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule .* public/index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry Olivier but that's inaccurate. The [QSA] ("Query String Append") flag is needed if you wish to *append* query string params to the one in the original request. If you wish merely to *preserve* the original request's query string, that is the default behavior and you do not need QSA. [And, if you wish to strip it off altogether, simply put a "?" at the end of the RewriteRule's target URL.]
HTH
Chris

Comment: From my own tests (watch my history on the answers about rewrite rules), what I can tell is: if you ever add something in the query, i.e. here: `public/index.php?aa=bb` then you will loose what was in the original request. So you may be right, but what I'm talking about here is a good principle not to forget because if you dont do that, you'll get into trouble one day or another. That's what I meant when I said "don't forget to keep what's after the ?" (maybe I didn't express myself properly, and if so, I'm sorry)

Comment: So, yes, all answers here are good, but no one mention what I could call a good principle. And this one adds no overhead, if you're right, and if the default behavior is to preserve the original request's query string - as long as it's not modified.

Comment: Fair enough. Adding [QSA] in rules where the target has no query string is harmless, other than cluttering the conf file a bit. If you prefer more verbose conf and protecting yourself against unintended side effects in the event you later modify the rule to add a query string to the target, ok, no harm done. My apache conf is really complex (mod_rewrite + mod_proxy + mod_wurfl + mod_setenvif + mod_headers, all interacting on the same logic) so I try to keep it as lean as possible, vs defensive conf for future changes I might never implement. YMMV. Have a nice day! :)